# How to import APK file on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

can anyone give me information on how to import an APK file (which was created on Animate) into Android Studio for testing on their emulator? looking around the internet I found only bits and pieces of information which were very confusing for the most part, none was a solid start to finish instruction. can anyone help me with either instruction or provide a good link?

Comment: What do you mean by importing?

Comment: ok let me ask you this, I have the APK file, what do I do now in order to run it in the emulator? nothing that I tried intuitively such as Open file or Open project worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't usually import apk file to run in Android Studio. If you have the apk file and want it to run in an emulator, you have to drag and drop the file in the emulator, it will show up in the download folder of the emulator, and from there you can install it.

Answer (score 0):

The debug verion of apk file is already generated and you can find it in your system at `AndroidStudioProjects\YourApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\debug`

Comment: I only tried to run APK file in the emulator. what am I missing?